# openlayers add points to GeoJSON layer and store them to postgis

Tags: postgis, openlayers

it should be a quite standard demand.

- load data from a database (in this case PostGis)
- add data to the layer (in this case points with attributes)
- save new data back to database

I use this functionality with google maps api, but I wan't to move to Openlayers (3/4).
Does anyone know a good example, tutorial how i could implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Openlayers works client side (in the browser). So allowing it to talk to a server side databases is a no-go.

You need to put a server side step in between (eg. a WFS server).

This answer gives you more details:
[How to connect OpenLayers to PostGIS data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52818/how-to-connect-openlayers-to-postgis-data)